# jQuery Table sorter Sorting of Float distance

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am using tablesorter to sort the table content. My table is as below.

```
<table class="results" border="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="header">No</th> 
        <th class="header">Distance</th>
        <th class="header">Diagnostic Fee</th>
        <th class="header">Regular Price </th>
        <th class="header">Company Price</th>
        <th class="">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td class="distance"><a>16.50 kms.</a></td>
        <td class="brand"><a>Credited</a></td>
        <td><a>$5</a></td>
        <td><a>$5<small>after 5% cash back</small></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
           <td>2</td>
        <td class="distance"><a>6.30 kms.</a></td>
        <td class="brand"><a>Credited</a></td>
        <td><a>$8</a></td>
        <td><a>$8<small>after 5% cash back</small></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td> 
        <td class="distance"><a>10.25 kms.</a></td>
        <td class="brand"><a>Credited</a></td>
        <td><a>$2</a></td>
        <td><a>$2<small>after 5% cash back</small></a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>​
```

I want to sort the table using distance and price. 
I am facing difficulty is solving table with distance, because distance is displayed in alphanumeric like "12 kms". So, The table is not getting sorted.

Can anyone advise how to parse the content by taking only digits?

here is the [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/umeshpatil86/wx6dU/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tablesorte has an option 'textExtraction', so you can define a function to go through the text before sorting. Example:

```
$("table").tablesorter({
        debug:false,  
        sortList: [[0, 0], [2, 0]],
        textExtraction: function(node) {  
            var $node = $(node)
            var text = $node.text();
            if ($node.hasClass('distance')) {
                text = text.replace('kms', '');
            };

            return text;
        }
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wx6dU/3/)

Comment: Would get rather messy with many different columns, better to use a parser.

Answer (score 5):

Tablesorter provides a way of defining additional parsers for cells in which it can't obtain data correctly. You need to define 2 parsers for the 2 columns you're interested in.

So you might have:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
  id: 'distance',
  is: function(s) {
    return false;
  },
  format: function(text, table, cell) {
    return parseFloat(text.replace('kms.', ''));
  },
  type: 'numeric'
});
```

for distance, and:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
   id: 'price',
   is: function(s) {
     return false;
   },
   format: function(text, table, cell) {
     return parseFloat(text.replace('$', ''));
   },
   type: 'numeric'
 });
```

for price. You then tell tablesorter which columns to use the parses on, so:

```
$("table").tablesorter({
  debug:false,  
  sortList: [[0, 0], [2, 0]],
  headers: {
    1: {
      sorter: 'distance'
    },
    3: {
      sorter: 'price'
    }
  }
});​
```

Comment: +1. I only did because, jsfiddle works well and code is less. OS should allow to accept multiple answer :)